# Shiurim from Rabbi Azriel Chaim Goldfein Zatzal

Tags: product-recommendation, adult-learning, speeches-addresses

Where can one obtain Shiurim from Rabbi Azriel Chaim Goldfein Zatzal? Rabbi Goldfein was the Rosh HaYeshiva of Yeshiva Gedolah of Johannesburg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the public shiurim of Rabbi Azriel Chaim Goldfein, z"l, Founder and Rosh HaYeshivah of the Yeshivah Gedolah of Johannesburg, are available for download.

To access the shiurim, please follow the links below (if you are unable to click on them or if clicking on them results in an error message, please copy and paste the links into your browser).

The shiurim are divided into three categories: parsha, yom tov, and special topics. Please note, each folder of shiurim contains an index for the shiurim in that category.

Parsha Shiurim 1 – 450 link:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7rnT3dsnVuLa2Q5ZE5scmxXWlk&usp=sharing

Parsha Shiurim 451 – 616 link:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByFFs3GqTdwaaXNoWGNjLUtvUE0&usp=sharing

Yom Tov Shiurim link:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9OxqzObWrYWbjZhQzZwLWdJQlE&usp=sharing

Special Shiurim link:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByFFs3GqTdwaT04wRHJOLWtiQ2c&usp=sharing

Comment: Wow! This is a goldmine!